# »Für was« vs. »wofür« – gibt es Unterschiede und Regeln?

Tags: difference, question, interrogative

Macht es einen Unterschied, ob man

> Wofür ist das gut?

oder

> Für was ist das gut?

fragt? Wenn ja: warum? Wie lässt sich entscheiden, welche Formulierung richtig ist?

Comment: "wofür" klingt in meinen Ohren auf jeden Fall schöner. Woran das liegt, weiß ich nicht. ;-)

Comment: weitere Beispiele:
von wo - woher;
zu wem - wohin?

Comment: *Wohin* ist nicht äquivalent zu *zu wem*. Wohin gehst du? - Nach Berlin. - Und zu wem? - Zu Peter.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Die Frage beantwortet der Zwiebelfisch:

[An was erkennt man guten Stil?](http://www.spiegel.de/schulspiegel/0,1518,376735,00.html)

Es ist also eine Frage des Stils, oder vielmehr der Umgangs- oder Standardsprache. Die Antwort auf die konkrete Frage (wie entscheidet man, welche Form man verwendet): Korrekt ist immer *wofür*, umgangssprachlich ist auch *für was* gebräuchlich.

Ich zitiere mal die Tabelle aus dem Artikel, die ist für Deutschlernende sicherlich interessant:

umgangssprachlich - standardsprachlich

- auf was - worauf
- aus was - woraus
- bei was - wobei
- durch was - wodurch
- für was - wofür
- gegen was - wogegen
- hinter was - wohinter
- in was - worin
- mit was - womit
- nach was - wonach
- neben was - woneben
- über was - worüber
- um was - worum
- unter was - worunter
- von was - wovon
- vor was - wovor
- zu was - wozu
- zwischen was - wozwischen

Witzig, dass in der Liste ausgerechnet "an was" - "woran" nicht auftaucht. Danke an Explorer. "Woraufhin" passt auch noch in die Liste. Da scheint es aber keine umgangssprachliche Form zu geben - der Duden hat als Bedeutung "auf welche Sache hin" oder "auf welchen Vorgang hin".

Comment: Auch "woraufhin" und "Woran".

Comment: @Explorer: "Woran" habe ich ergänzt. Seltsam, dass das in der Liste fehlt. Bei "woraufhin" bin ich mir hingegen nicht sicher. Wie wäre da denn das umgangssprachliche Äquivalent? "Auf was hin"? :)

Comment: Huh, keine Ahnung darüber! "darauf was"?

Comment: Hmm, eigentlich wird "woraufhin" genauso verwendet wie die anderen Beispiele in der Liste. Aber finde trotzdem keine richtige umgangssprachliche Form :)

Comment: "Woraufhin" setzt eine zeitliche Sequenz voraus. Ein umgangssprachliches Äquivalent könnte sein: "Nach was?"

Comment: Und Sick weiß, dass das besserer Stil ist, weil … er das so gelernt hat? Er da eben so ein Gefühl hat? Viel reden, ohne Argumente zu haben, ist Sicks Stärke.

Comment: Es ist schade, dass falsche Zusammensetzungen nicht als falsch, sondern als „umgangssprachlich“ definiert werden. Das suggeriert dem Lernenden, dass das die eigentlich richtige Form ist, weil sie „jeder“ spricht. „An was“ und Konsorten sind schlichtweg falsch und klingen auch falsch. Wenn das aber nicht kommuniziert wird, ist das für ’n Arsch, und Google stellt ganz offiziell die Frage „Für was ist ein Energieausweis?“. Tataa … schon zu spät ;)

Answer (score 5):

[Hier](http://www.korrekturen.de/forum.pl/md/read/id/36048/sbj/wofuer-fuer-was/) ist eine gute Antwort auf "welches man benutzt":

> Weiter steht in "Richtiges und gutes
>   Deutsch": "für was/wofür: Die
>   Verbindung 'für + was' kommt in der
>   gesprochenen Sprache recht häufig vor.
>   Im geschriebenen Standarddeutsch wird
>   in der Regel 'wofür' verwendet.
>
> Übrigens wieder ein gutes Beispiel
>   dafür, dass der Duden doch sehr
>   vorsichtig mit einer allzu strengen
>   Festlegung bzw. Unterscheidung in
>   "Standarddeutsch" und "Umgangssprache"
>   ist: "recht häufig", "in der Regel".
>   Soll wohl heißen, es ist nicht so
>   richtig falsch, aber auch nicht so
>   richtig richtig.

Answer (score 3):

**Wofür** ist eine Spur förmlicher **für was**.

Die Bedeutung ist gleich.

Comment: Also nur eine Sache des Umgangs, welches man benutzt?

Comment: Bezogen auf gesprochene Sprache ja. In der Schriftsprache gilt wofür als gebildeter.

Comment: Nur um das zu ergänzen: "Wofür" kann (wie jeder gute Stil) auch deplaziert wirken. Auf mich würde es im Alltag leicht gestelzt, bei einem (offensichtlichen) Nicht-Muttersprachler wie aus dem Lehrbuch gelernt wirken. Aber das ist eine ziemliche Stil- und Geschmacksfrage und kommt tatsächlich auf das konkrete Umfeld an.

Comment: @ladybug: Verglichen mit anderen Dingen für guten Stil ist *wofür* aber noch relativ harmlos. Da kann ich mir schlimmeres vorstellen ;)

Comment: Das stimmt, ja. :)

Answer (score 2):

›Für was‹ und alle anderen Zusammensetzungen aus Präposition und ›was‹ sind sehr prominent in der gesprochenen Sprache.

In der Standardsprache gilt die Konvention, ›was + Präposition‹ durch eine Zusammensetzung mit ›wo‹ zu ersetzen --› wofür.

Das macht ›für was‹ nicht falsch, sondern nur ungebräuchlich in der Schriftsprache.

Answer (score 1):

Im Umgang wird beides benutzt. Richtig ist „ wofür“.
Zuerst kommt das Interrogativpronomen und dann die
Präposition.